# Use AsyncStorage for loading user data in react native

Tags: react-native, scrollview, asyncstorage

I'm new with react native and I'm trying to write a to do application. I'm using AsyncStorage to store the tasks and then I want to load them each time user opens the app. Here you may see some of my codes:

//Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet ,
     Text,
     View, 
     TextInput,
     ScrollView,
     TouchableOpacity,
     KeyboardAvoidingView,
     AsyncStorage
    } from 'react-native'
import Note from './Note'
   export default class Main extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'To do list',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
    },
  };

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      noteArray: [],
      noteText: '',
      dueDate: ''
    }
  }
  async saveUserTasks(value) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:userTask',JSON.stringify(value));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error saving data" + error);
    }
  }
   getUserTasks = async() =>{
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:userTask');
      if (value !== null){
        this.state.noteArray = JSON.parse(value)
     }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
    }
  }

render() {
  this.getUserTasks()
  // This is where I handle each item for my scrollview which I copied from a toturial and I have issues here.
    let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val,key) => {
      return <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val}
      deleteMethod={ () => this.deleteNote(key)}
      goToDetailPage= {() => this.goToNoteDetail(key)}
       />
    });
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return(
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' style={styles.keyboard}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContainer}>
                {notes}
            </ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.footer}>
                <TextInput
                onChangeText={(noteText) => this.setState({noteText})}
                style={styles.textInput}
                placeholder='What is your next Task?'
                placeholderTextColor='white'
                underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent'
                >
                </TextInput>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.addNote.bind(this)} style={styles.addButton}>
                <Text style={styles.addButtonText}> + </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
   </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      );
    }
    addNote(){
      if (this.state.noteText){
        var d = new Date();
        this.state.noteArray.push({ 
        'creationDate': d.getFullYear() + "/" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getDay(), 'taskName': this.state.noteText,'dueDate':'YYYY/MM/DD'
        });
        this.setState({noteArray:this.state.noteArray})
        this.setState({noteText: ''});
        this.saveUserTasks(this.state.noteArray) 
      }
    }
    deleteNote(key){
      this.state.noteArray.splice(key,1);
      this.setState({noteArray: this.state.noteArray})
      this.saveUserTasks(this.state.noteArray)       
    }
    goToNoteDetail=(key)=>{   
      this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailsScreen', {
        selectedTask: this.state.noteArray[key],
      });
    }     
}
//Styles goes here
```

My problem is that when I open the app I can't see the list from storage until I try to type something in my textInput, even without adding it. which I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use setState not this.state.noteArray

```
if (value !== null){
    this.setState({ noteArray: JSON.parse(value)});
 }
```

Comment: By the way I want to push another object to my noteArray and save it again in my Details.js. but I get error which says this.noteArray is undefined. Do have any idea why?

Comment: use this.state.noteArray

Comment: Sorry for miss typing. I'm using that:
this.state.noteArray.push({ 
      'creationDate': selectedTask['creationDate'], 'taskName': selectedTask['taskName'],'dueDate':this.state.dueData
      });
      this.setState({noteArray:this.state.noteArray})
      this.saveUserTasks(this.state.noteArray) 
    }